# How can user invoke superuser command?

Tags: qnx

I created a user group and a user, when i log onto it and type su on the terminal.

I get this error `su error: Password and Shadow files on different devices`

How do i fix this issue?

Comment: How did you create the user group and the user?

Comment: i got it working , by copying the /etc/opasswd to etc/passwd, and /etc/oshadow to /etc/shadow.